# How to change css by using tag or class name in typescript?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, ionic2

I want to change top position of element in ionic 2 using their tag name or class name just like we do in JavaScript.

Comment: Any piece of code? an example? What have you tried and failed?

Comment: i have to change this value                                                                             <ion-tabber role="tablist" class="show-tabber" style="top:56">                         i want to change top using ts

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: The [How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please you can try

```
//Get the element by tag name
let element = document.getElementsByTagName('Tag_name');
```

Remember it when you get an element by tag it will return an array.

Please add an example, so I can help you

Comment: i have to change this value <ion-tabber role="tablist" class="show-tabber" style="top:56"> i want to change top using ts

Comment: **CSS Solution:** I notice that you a class maybe you can use show-tabber class and set .show-tabber{top:56px;}